# wcf extension not invoked

Tags: wcf, rest

Wcf extension is working fine on local iis. however,when i deployed it on windows server 2008, I got the following errors.

An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for system.serviceModel/behaviors: Extension element 'ErrorHandlerExtension' cannot be added to this element.  Verify that the extension is registered in the extension collection at system.serviceModel/extensions/behaviorExtensions.

I left a space after each comma, but it did not work.

Pls give me some insight.

Answer (score 0):

In general this could be caused by one of the following problems:

- A difference in the configuration file between local iis and server
- The dll containing the extension was not deployed to the server
- The rights of the identity of the app pool on the server are limited

Answer (score 0):

the solution for this case that I have solved : microsoft netframework version compatible. when I was installed the netframework 4.5 the problem has solved.